# What is CNAME exactly DNS entries of Domain Hosting

Tags: hosting

In what purpose we have to configure CNAME entr in DNS entry.  Is there way possible to configure 2 domains for single hosting.  IN this scenerio, how CNAME help for us.

thanks.

Comment: Here is the simple guide you can read this :https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/cname-record/

Answer (score 2):

A Canonical Name record (abbreviated as CNAME record) is a type of resource record in the Domain Name System (DNS) used to specify that a domain name is an alias for another domain, the "canonical" domain. All information, including subdomains, IP addresses, etc., are defined by the canonical domain.

This can prove convenient when running multiple services (like an FTP server and a webserver; each running on different ports) from a single IP address. One can, for example, point ftp.example.com and www.example.com to the DNS A record for example.com, which in turn points to the IP address. Then, if the IP address ever changes, one only has to record the change in one place within the network: in the DNS A record.

CNAME records must always point to another domain name, never directly to an IP address.

More info from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

Answer (score 1):

CNAME is just an alias. I can see it being useful in cases such that you want to hand out a bunch of subdomains to each client but they all point to the same source and that source is not necessarily an IP Address because it's load balanced between a few IP Addresses. I would say it offers different levels of abstraction in this case.

There is a way to configure 2 domains for a single hosting. I am assuming by hosting you mean a server hosting. You can use nginx to achieve this.

```
server { 
  server_name example1.com;
  #proxy to appropriate port etc
}

server { 
  server_name example2.com;
  #proxy to appropriate port etc
}
```

Take a look at this post which probably explains a bit more in detail for the handling of two domains/subdomains.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The CNAME record is the canonical name record which is used to create an alias name to other. For an example if a user has the data on the domain files.example.com and the other user is needed to search the same content which is with files.example.com from myfiles.example.com.

Then in this case the cname record helps. so one should point the domain myfiles.example.com to files.example.com in the DNS entries.